# Accessor declared inside the class, and defined outside the class doesn't work

Tags: c++, class, accessor

```
//inside the class NutritionData, declaration
double getCaloriesPerServing() const;

//Outside the class Nutrition Data, definition
double NutritionData::getCaloriesPerServing() const {
    calPerServing = calFromCarb+calFromFat+calFromProtein;
    return calPerServing;
}
```

Error: says

> the expression calPerServing must be a modifiable lvalue.

Instructor directions:
1.Add a const member function named getCaloriesPerServing that returns the total calories from carb, protein and fat. Again, don't forget to mark this function as a const member function. Define this function outside of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to be certain without seeing the class definition for `NutritionData`, but it looks like you have a member variable called `calPerServing`. Because you are inside a `const` member function, that variable is `const` in this context; you can't assign to it:

```
calPerServing = ... // it's const here!
```

You probably want `calPerServing` to be a local variable inside the `getCaloriesPerServing` function, that is only used for this particular calculation:

```
double NutritionData::getCaloriesPerServing() const {
    int totalCalPerServing = calFromCarb+calFromFat+calFromProtein;
    return totalCalPerServing;
}
```

---

Many people find it helpful to follow a naming convention to help distinguish member variables from local variables or function parameters. For example, at my company this code might look like:

```
    int totalCalPerServing = d_calFromCarb+d_calFromFat+d_calFromProtein;
    //  ^^^ local            ^^ member     ^^ member    ^^ member
```